# php 8.2 install grpc in XAMPP

Tags: php, grpc

I am attempting to set up the Cloud API in PHP, and currently, I need to install the gRPC extension. Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc#c-implementation

I have downloaded the latest '.dll' file from the pecl official website. However, when I start the server, I encounter the following error:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: grpc: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20210902\nPHP compiled with module API=20220829
```

Upon checking, I found that the downloaded dll is for PHP 8.1, but the PHP version I am using is 8.2. I cannot downgrade my PHP version because some libraries (such as mysqlite) require a minimum of PHP 8.2 to run. However, I couldn't find a dll for PHP 8.2 on the pecl website. All I found were tgz files, and currently, I don't know how to convert them to dll.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue? Thank you very much.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue? Thank you very much.

Comment: `tgz` is just a compression format; I'm sure you can unpack it on the command line, if not using a program like 7zip.

Comment: You'll need to compile it on your own or via pecl if it even works on Windows.

Comment: @Daedalus I do but I cant find any .dll file in this folder. Do I miss something?

Comment: @soulseekah how I can compile it.